# How to add multiple text to video in iOS as shown in image?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYtFi.png)

i have to add multiple text to video like a profile page.there should be proper alignment of text.i am facing problem in alignment and adding multiple text. help me out on this!!

```
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoLayer.masksToBounds=YES;
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];

    CATextLayer *titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    titleLayer.string = @" Candidate Name ";
    titleLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain(@"Helvetica");
    titleLayer.fontSize =15.0f;
    [titleLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, videoSize.width, 30)];  // CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f,videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    titleLayer.opacity=0.0;
    //?? titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
   // titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.5f, 0.5f, videoSize.width, 30); //You may need to adjust this for proper display
    [aLayer addSublayer:titleLayer]; //ONLY IF WE ADDED TEXT


    CATextLayer *titleLayer1 = [CATextLayer layer];
    titleLayer1.string = @" Raman Srivastava";
    titleLayer1.font = CFBridgingRetain(@"Helvetica");
    titleLayer1.fontSize =15.0f;
    [titleLayer1 setFrame:CGRectMake(25.0f,20.0f,videoSize.width, 30)];
    titleLayer1.opacity=0.0;
    //?? titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    titleLayer1.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft;
    // titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, videoSize.width, videoSize.height / 6); //You may need to adjust this for proper display
    [aLayer addSublayer:titleLayer1]; //ONLY IF WE ADDED TEXT
```

Comment: UITableView with custom UITableViewCell ? UIStackView ?

Comment: @Larme see my updates question

Answer (score 0):

You can then also set the resizing mask on the layer so that changes to the view will be reflected in the layer.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? Do not post comments as answer if you do not have enough reputation to comment yet. I have downvoted, edit it and make it an actual answer and I will upvote you.